# Importing p12 file via iOS Share Extension provides wrong Data

Tags: ios, swift, attachment, share-extension, p12

I am trying to export a mail attachment (which is a `.p12` file) to my iOS app using a Share Extension.

This is the function to process Share Extension attachments:

```
@IBAction func processAttachment() {
    guard let item = self.extensionContext?.inputItems[0] as? NSExtensionItem, 
          let provider = item.attachments?.first,   
          provider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("com.rsa.pkcs-12") else { 
              extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil); 
              return 
          }

    provider.loadDataRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: "com.rsa.pkcs-12") { (p12Data, error) in
        //Process Data here
    }
```

The problem I am having is that I am getting a decoding error (OSStatus) `-26275` (aka `This certificate could not be decoded`) when I am trying to import it with `SecPKCS12Import`.

I tried the same approach by replacing the data within the closure by a local file loading using:

```
let pkcsFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "certificate", withExtension: "p12")!
let pkcsData = try! Data(contentsOf: pkcsFileURL)
```

The decode of the Data from the local file is successful so far.

Then, I realise that the Data coming from the attachment and the local file does not match. While data coming from attachment is `9856 bytes`, the one locally is `5747 bytes`.

I am sharing from iOS Outlook app installed in the app which show the origin file is 6KB (much closer to the Data read from the local file).

Maybe data from attachment is nos decoded properly, it is curious that the wrong data is almos double size that the original.

I am reading attachment data properly?

**UPDATE**

I think all the problem is caused because the attachment is shared as a binary.